# Solving ODEs in the Complex Plane for General z

Tags: differential-equations, complex

I saw with the new 12.0 update, they have introduced expanded functionality for [solving complex ODEs](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/complex-visualization/solutions-of-complex-odes.html?product=language). In the given example, they solve for $y(t)$ and plot results using the new `ReImPlot[]` function. I was wondering, however, is it possible to solve an equation for a general complex variable, `z`, where $z(t) = r(t)e^{i\psi(t)}$ and your ODE looks something like:

$\dot{z}(t) = a z(t)$,

where $a$ is some real valued constant. Breaking it up as they have done in the above example (with $y(t)$ multiplied by a complex exponential) is difficult because evaluating $\dot{z}(t)$ gives a sum of terms proportional to $\dot{r}(t)$ and $\dot{\psi}(t)$. Thus, I was wondering, is it possible to keep the equations in terms of $z(t)$ and then solve for the expression of $z(t)$ that I have given above?

Thanks!

Note: While I know this example can be analytically split into real and imaginary parts, I am looking to avoid doing that because I would like to work with functions that would be very difficult to make the split.